# JSP on JDeveloper, error: "identifier OracleJspRuntime not found"

Tags: java, jsp

I am a developer with `.NET` experience but I am now dealing with a `J2EE` application (with `JSP` and `EJP` projects ) which I am trying -without much luck so far- to make it work.

I am now getting the error

> Error(22,17): identifier OracleJspRuntime not found

when I try to build it.
googling the error message I found that I may need to add JSP Runtime to my project libraries ,but which libraries exactly that I need to add ?
Given the fact that I am completely new to the J2EE world, what am I missing here?,what are this error message trying to say ?

Answer (score 0):

I found the hack to it ,just added reference to JSP Runtime under Extension tab in add library dialog box (I am using JDeveloper10G)